# check var in between

Tags: irc, mirc

```
if (%var == 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5) { }
```

So what u want is to check whether the variable's value is in between 1-5 in mirc?

I can do it like this:

```
if (%var == 1) {  }
if (%var == 2) {  }
if (%var == 3) {  }
if (%var == 4) {  }
if (%var == 5) {  }
```

**But is there any shorter way?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiomatic answer is:

```
if (%var isnum 1-5) {

}
```